# How to change OAuth 2.0 account on google form

Tags: google-forms

We have several Google forms that were created.  These forms also send out emails with results, and the FROM: account in the OWNER of the form.  The person that created the forms and is the owner of the forms has left the company.  So how can I change the owner of this form, or change it so the from email account comes from a different account.

Thanks

Rudy